# express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option app.js:27:9

Tags: deprecated, express-session

I typed npm start to run my program but this is the comment that U received in the terminal: express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option app.js:27:9. I don't understand how this issue needs to be fixed.
This is the code from app.js:27:9

```
app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    is_logged_in: false,
}))
```

Comment: check the existence of `SESSION_SECRET`

Comment: tldr; `express-session` was not given your secret. the value in `process.env.SESSION_SECRET` (or whatever you passed to the `secret` option) is _empty_.

Answer (score 26):

Make sure you added the SESSION_SECRET in .env file.
If yes, then in your app.js, add this

`const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Make sure dotenv is installed: `npm i dotenv`

Answer (score 4):

You need to load all your environment variables. at line one on the server.js file write this...

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { require('dotenv').config() }`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and the culprit was adding the `SESSION_SECRET` to my `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on running on Linux server:
Add environment variables here

```
edit /etc/environment
```

Add:

```
export SESSION_SECRET="Ssdsd@#e$#Rfe@#$d#$#"
```

You can check if this is correct created with:

```
printenv or printenv SESSION_SECRET
```

..and yes, and in your express:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config() 

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
});
```

Comment: I have added .env file and dotenv package config too. but i still get deprecated warning message ' express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option'. I found that env variable value was some how empty i have modified the line secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'myvaluehere' and now warning gone away. thanks

Comment: but what's the use of writing secret : process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'myvaluehere'.  we use dotenv to hide the secrets and by doing the thing that you mentioned the vaule is easily accessible to the person who opens the app.js. Instead you could have written it directly and not used dotenv

Answer (score 0):

If you added the SESSION_SECRET in your .env file already(SESSION_SECRET='this is my session'),then do require dotenv in your app.js file similar to the following:

const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path:'./.env'});

mentioning path is important otherwise it's not detecting SESSION_SECRET from .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem go checkout wether your .env and .gitignore files are in the same folder where server.js is
.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Create file: config.js

```
const cfg = {
    ...,
    secured_key: '06vUSNEzq1z9U476UrMEx7xIOPGYfu2m',
    ...
}

module.exports = cfg;
```

In app.js

```
...
const cfg = require('./config');
...

app.use(session({
    secret: cfg.secured_key,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
...
```

This error resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Put the dotenv config up the lines where you are exporting the files, for example:

```
const express = require("express"); require("dotenv").config(); const dbConnect = require("./config/mongo"); const userSession = require("./config/session");
```